# Why does my script return a syntax error?

Tags: bash, scripts

I wrote this script, but I don't know why I have a syntax error:

```
#!/bin/bash
    echo Indica la fecha de hoy en formato dd-mm-aaaa
    read date
    echo Indica la hora actual en formato hh-mm
    read hora
    mkdir -p /re/plugins
    shopt -s extglob
    cp -R /files/spigot/plugins/!(dynmap) /re/plugins
    shopt -u extglob
    cp -R /files/spigot/world /re
    zip -r "$date"-"$hora".zip plugins world
    mv /re/*.zip /var/www/html/backup
    rm -R /re
    Echo copia de seguridad realizada correctamente el dia "$date" a las "$hora"h > /log.txt
```

The output

```
root@alex:/home/alex# sh pb.sh
Indica la fecha de hoy en formato dd-mm-aaaa
aaa
Indica la hora actual en formato hh-mm
sdf
pb.sh: 7: pb.sh: shopt: not found
pb.sh: 8: pb.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
root@alex:/home/alex#
```

Comment: Don't run `bash` scripts using `sh` (which is `dash`): see [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ it works wonders (I'm beginner and needed to write script for myself)

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is right here:

```
root@alex:/home/alex# sh pb.sh
```

`shopt` is a shell builtin (see `type shopt`). `/bin/sh` isn't bash on Ubuntu, but a compatibility shell called dash. Dash doesn't have `shopt`.

Since the first line of your script is the shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`) you can just run your script like this:

```
./pb.sh
```

and it should work fine. You may need to set the file as executable by running:

```
chmod +x pb.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

> pb.sh: 8: pb.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

The `!(dynmap)` syntax is only recognized when the `extglob` shell option has been set, and it hadn't:

> pb.sh: 7: pb.sh: shopt: not found

The `shopt` command wasn't found because it's a shell builtin and the particular shell that ran the script doesn't support it, as [Seth's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/692381/132455) explains.

Comment: Good idea for clarifying the syntax error. I thought it was obvious but better be safe than sorry :)